# shim-signed just won't ever update

Tags: linux-mint, apt, package-management

On my *Dell Inspiron 15 Gaming 7577* machine (7th gen Intel if relevant), running Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon.. for about a month I see this in my update script output:

```
Command: apt-get -o APT::Get::Always-Include-Phased-Updates=true dist-upgrade
--------------------------------------
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  shim-signed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Considering I force update phased packages, the following should be of no help/problem:

```
$ apt-cache policy shim-signed
shim-signed:
  Installed: 1.51+15.4-0ubuntu9
  Candidate: 1.51.3+15.7-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1.51.3+15.7-0ubuntu1 500 (phased 71%)
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.51+15.4-0ubuntu9 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

---

Did `apt` start ignoring the `APT::Get::Always-Include-Phased-Updates=true` option? I don't know.

Any insight will be valued, thank you.

---

```
# apt-get --simulate install shim-signed
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 base-files : Conflicts: base-files:i386
 base-files:i386 : Conflicts: base-files
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

The above I just ran to simulate the update, I hope it helps you help me.

---

```
$ apt-cache policy base-files{,:i386}
base-files:
  Installed: 21.1.0
  Candidate: 21.1.0
  Version table:
 *** 21.1.0 700
        700 http://packages.linuxmint.com vera/upstream amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     12ubuntu4.3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     12ubuntu4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
base-files:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 12ubuntu4.3
  Version table:
     12ubuntu4.3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
     12ubuntu4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
```

@Stephen's comment ^^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the recent changes in `shim-signed` is this dependency:

```
grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.191~) | grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.191~) | base-files (<< 12.3)
```

The last part of the disjunction is the one causing issues: since Linux Mint ships `base-files` version 21.1.0, the requirement can’t be met. `apt` considers that `base-files:i386` might satisfy the constraint: since Mint doesn’t ship an `i386` version of that package, the candidate is the Ubuntu version; but other parts of the system require `base-files:amd64` and the resulting conflicts can’t be resolved, which is what leads to the somewhat surprising error involving `i386`.

If you really want to upgrade `shim-signed`, you could try installing `grub-efi-amd64-signed`, but I don’t know what the impact of that might be on your ability to boot your system. Personally I would ignore the upgrade (I know, that’s easy for me to say, I’m not running Mint).