# How to solve unmet dependencies related to each other?

Tags: apt

How can I solve the following issue on Linux Mint?

```
sudo apt install shim-signed
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 base-files : Conflicts: base-files:i386
 base-files:i386 : Conflicts: base-files
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of `shim-signed` is not installable on Mint; see [shim-signed just won't ever update](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/738796/86440) for details.

You need to install the version originally provided with Ubuntu 22.04:

```
sudo apt install shim-signed=1.51+15.4-0ubuntu9
```